# Win is trying to repair while booting > cmd > chkdsk C: filesystem is unknown

Tags: linux, windows, boot, partitioning

This is my first question so please be kind. Recently i did my first installation of Ubuntu.(yesterday, ever since i tried to repair it, did not found anything helpfull) I wanted dual boot with windows 10. While installing, i split my free space into 2 partitions 700G and 200G so i can have something there and over there.. so i installed(at least i thought so) linux on 200Gig space. After succesfull instalation i tried to boot windows, but that did not help, its stuck on repairing. I tried every single option but most recently i found command "chkdsk \f \r" that didnt work because my root partition is X: . So i tried "chkdsk C:" nd my kind computer answered something along "filesystem on C: is unknown. Cant proceed" I really need only my data, nothing else matters. Also i tried to update grub. Not helpfull. Thanks for all kinds of answers, I don't know if further information is needed, please be kind. And if there is similar question, i didn't found it. I am trying to help myself at least for 20h straight. Thx for all suggestions.

Comment: Remove the hard drive and Use a usb to hard drive adapter to get to your data using another PC

Comment: If you boot an Ubuntu Live Disc, you should be able to access all the hard disc partitions and copy off any data you need to a USB drive. If it's not already installed, you should be able to install and run [boot-repair](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/) (install from `.deb`).

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer for UEFI installed Windows
(which is most Windows 10 pre-installed machines).

Boot using Windows 10 USB installer. 
At the first screen, type <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to get to command line. 
Type the following commands:

```
diskpart [enter]

list disk [enter]

select disk # [enter]   (Replace # with the disk number where Windows is installed.)

list volume [enter]

select volume # [enter] (where # is one in list that says EFI.)

assign letter=a  [enter] 

select volume # [enter] (where # is where Windows is installed.)

assign letter=W [enter]

exit [enter]

chkdsk /f w: [enter]

chkdsk /f a: [enter]
```

Then:

```
bcdboot W:\windows /s a: /f UEFI
```

When done, reboot the machine.